# Scons boost libraries in two different places

Tags: c++, boost, scons

Our system has boost installed in two different places - one in /usr/... and the other is a custom install in another directory. I want to only include the headers/libs from the custom install but scons keeps picking up the standard path in /usr/...

Is there a way to force scons to only see the headers/libs in the custom directory. I have added this path to my CPPPATH variable, but the /usr/include path is also there which I do need for other c++ headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include directories ("-I") are searched in left-to-right order  and before standard paths (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)

Try prepending your CPPPATH using Prepend:

```
env = Environment()
env.Prepend(CPPPATH = ['/opt/boost'])
```

Here's the reference for Prepend:
http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/x1444.html#AEN1719

Comment: The OP may need to do the same for the library paths with the LIBPATH construction variable if using any of the boost libs.

Comment: This doesn't work, it seems like the /usr/include /usr/lib directories are predefined somehow by scons I don't see them in any environment variables

Comment: Nevermind I must have been doing something wrong it's working now using the Prepend option